# Is it a Lake, Cove, Tidal Creek or a Spring?

Tags: geology

We are very confused by this water body. This is called "Carolina Lake" however other suggests that it is not a Lake but a cove. Other say it is a tidal creek for it is influenced by tide. It was already explored beneath and found to have spring underneath (head of the sperm-like channel). It flows to the ocean 9 km away. What are your thoughts? It is a lake, cove or spring or tidal creek?

[image]

Comment: I doubt that the river/creek is called "Carolina Lake".

Comment: Notice that the creek continues upstream of the oval feature.

Comment: Where is this located?  Having some context of the broader area around this would make the question easier to answer.